# Check to see if the Select dropdown value is at 0 then prevent the anchor from being clicked else take select value and put into the href of anchor?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of options in a select with an anchor below. I want the first option in the select to not be able to have the anchor clicked causing a new tab and the same page to load. Here is the HTML + JS

```js
const stateSubmitBtn = document.getElementById('state-select-button');
const stateValue = document.getElementById('states');

function checkStateValue() {
    if(stateValue[0] == stateValue[0]) {
        console.log(stateValue);
        console.log('if statement')
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if(stateValue[0] !== stateValue[0]) {
        console.log(stateValue[0]);
        console.log('else statement')
        let value = document.getElementById('states');
        console.log('fail');
        stateSubmitBtn.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        stateSubmitBtn.setAttribute('href', stateValue.value);
    };
}

stateSubmitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    checkStateValue();
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <select name="States" id="states">
      <option disabled selected value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="California">California</option>
      <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
      <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
      <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
      <option value="North-Carolina">North Carolina</option>
      <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
      <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
  </select>
  
  <div>
    <a id="state-select-button">
        Select
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you did not define event

Answer (score 0):

The if condition in your checkStateValue function doesn't make sense, as it's comparing the same value to itself. You need to compare the value of the selected option and also pass the event object to the checkStateValue function so you can call event.preventDefault() properly and do check the logic for setting the href attribute on the stateSubmitBtn once again it is mixed up a little.

```
const stateSubmitBtn = document.getElementById('state-select-button');
const stateValue = document.getElementById('states');

function checkStateValue(event) {
  if (stateValue.value === "") {
    console.log('if statement');
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log('else statement');
    stateSubmitBtn.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    stateSubmitBtn.setAttribute('href', stateValue.value);
  }
}

stateSubmitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  checkStateValue(event);
});

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <select name="States" id="states">
      <option disabled selected value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="California">California</option>
      <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
      <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
      <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
      <option value="North-Carolina">North Carolina</option>
      <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
      <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
  </select>
  
  <div>
    <a id="state-select-button">
        Select
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```